# Use MySQL to access Wordpress database?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Just wondering if this is possible. A client I'm working with is looking to have a mobile version of their website. Instead of just trying to 'downsize' their current website, I'd like to create a tablet/phone version of their site that will only include a select few information that's currently in their Wordpress site. Ideally I'd like to create a separate site that uses PHP and mySQL and tap into the WP database and pull back the information that I need. Anyone know if that's possible to do?

Comment: WP defaults to using mysql... so what's the problem? Good luck figuring out the schema. WP's internals are a festering pit of evil.

Comment: Why do you think it's not possibile? WP uses mysql to connect to its database (and badly too, but that's another story)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, WordPress uses MySQL with a sensical schema. It also supports SQLite and the other standard RDBMS's.

You should consider writing new templates within WordPress rather than going directly to the database.  That would require writing much less PHP, and you're already stuck with some WP learning curve since you have to learn the schema anyway.